# Mod Rewrite path issues

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lamp

I have successfully created rewrite rules to handle URLs like

http://example.com/xyz

http://example.com/xyz/

http://example.com/xyz/abc

http://example.com/xyz/abc/

Here is the mod rewrite & regex:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)(?:\/)?$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)(?:\/)?$ /index.php?n=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)/([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)(?:\/)?$ /index.php?n=$2 [L]
```

This works great, but the problem is that when I go to http://example.com/xyz/abc, my script gets the correct input (n=abc) but the paths are messed up, so all relative URLs in my code are broken, as they are now relative to xyz instead of the root.

Is there a way around this at all? As you can see above I have tried to redirect to /index.php to force the path to be correct. My brain is fried after a long day of regex and code, so I hope it's not something disastrously trivial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The three options are:

1) Use a base tag (this will affect every relative URI on your page, including links, images, scripts, stylesheets and so on)

```
<base href="http://yoursite/">
```

2) Change all of your links to fully qualified URIs

```
<a href="http://yoursite/yourpage.html">
```

3) Use the "/" prefix to show that the path is relative to the root on each URI.

```
<a href="/yourpage.html">
```

I have personally used the base-tag option the most, which does get some bad press (from people that have used it without really understanding it). When it comes to mod_rewrite, the base tag is perfect as you probably DO want all your paths to be relative to the root, including all your images, css, scripts and links.

Comment: You and Welbog both had nice answers. Gave the accepted one to you as the underdog points wise. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Use the HTML [`base`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp) element to force all relative URLs to use a different path than the one the browser displays.

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/"/>
...
<a href="relative/url">link</a>
```

The relative URL will use "http://www.example.com" as its base, even if the browser thinks it's looking at the page "http://www.example.com/xyz/". So the link goes to "http://www.example.com/relative/url" instead of "http://www.example.com/xyz/relative/url"

And there's the Stack Overflow way of doing it, in which every URL is either an absolute path (to resources like images) or paths including the root (i.e. "/feeds/questions/123"), which avoid the relative path issues.

Comment: Note that changing the base URI will affect *every* relative URI and not just those that start with the URI path.

Answer (score 2):

*Edit: I assume you are talking about URLs in your HTML code, e.g. to images and stylesheets, that are broken.*

Nope, as far as I know there is no way around it, because the browser sees a path, and requests resources relative to it. It has nothing to do with the server, and there is nothing you can do.

You will either have to resort to a different splitter that is not interpreted as a directory splitter (e.g. underscores), or use absolute paths, or use the [<base> tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp). I have never used the base tag myself, however, and it is not very well regarded wherever you look. The best thing would probably be to switch to absolute paths.

Comment: thanks for your input... I kind of hope there is a way around it. Please let me know if you have reading that positively identifies this as the case and I will accept this answer.

Comment: Note that changing the base URI will affect *every* relative URI and not just those that start with the URI path.

Comment: @Antony: I'm quite sure you won't get around it if you continue using slashes - a path is a path. Have you considered using a different character for your virtual paths? That doesn't look as nice but does the job. I have seen commas used, which to my eye looks quite ok even though it's not entirely legal.

Comment: @pekka I unfortunately need to use this URL structure due to project requirements, but I do agree a different delimiter would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Pekka Gaiser: Using other characters instead of the segment separator `/` has a complete different meaning for the URL as the segments normally represent a hierarchy.

Comment: @Gumbo: I'm totally with you, but if there really is no other choice, who cares what my URL looks like? Either way, it's a valid path to a resource. Not that I'm in favour of that solution. I prefer proper, absolute paths as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

modify your last RewriteRule to include the path. you have the path in the regular expression.

```
RewriteRule ^/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)/([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)(?:\/)?$ $1/index.php?n=$2 [L]
```

or alternatively (depending on what you are trying to achieve):

```
RewriteRule ^/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)/([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)(?:\/)?$ /index.php?n=$1/$2 [L]
```

Comment: thats kind of the reverse of what I want - it needs to be using the root.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the BASE element in my pages as a shortcut instead of changing all urls. Add the base element as follows:

```
<base href="/">
```

And here are the results:

```
This:    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="my.css">
Becomes: <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/my.css">

This:    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="include/my.js"></script>
Becomes: <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/include/my.js"></script>

This:    <a href="foo.html">
Becomes: <a href="/foo.html">

This:    <a href="foo/bar.html">
Becomes: <a href="/foo/bar.html">
```

You can always override the base tag where necessary:

```
This:    <a href="/foo">
Remains: <a href="/foo">

This:    <a href="/foo/bar/">
Remains: <a href="/foo/bar/">
```

Comment: Note that changing the base URI will affect *every* relative URI and not just those that start with the URI path.