# .htacces mod_rewrite path is wrong

Tags: php, .htaccess

My website currently runs on PHP with direct links like

```
www.example.com/index.php?go=somewhere
```

I like to build clean likes that don't show that the page is php and look like ordonary html links, for this i used a .htaccess file witht he following content

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^exampleCategory/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    index.php?go=$1    [NC,L]
```

i except a like looking like this:

```
example.com/exampleCategory/item7
```

to become

```
example.com/index.php?go=item7
```

which partially works, but it seems that the index.php uses the given path instead of the server root path

when index.php load the item site, no css and no images apperar, likely because the image links look like this

```
example.com/exampleCategory/item7/images/item7/item7_1.jpg
```

instead of

```
example.com/images/item7/item7_1.jpg
```

In case i call the site via the php link, it works perfectly.

What could be the issue / how to fix this problem?
Since categories will be dynamic and expandable, its impossible to create server paths matching the given path. I would like to have a central image folder.

Comment: paste you .htaccess full code here

Comment: my .htacces code is already up in the post, its just two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the details given above it seems like you did not exclude directory and files.

This code is tested in windows running WAMP. If any issue write that down below in the comment section.

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f

RewriteRule ^exampleCategory/([\w\-]+)/?$ index.php?go=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I tried this, but now i get error 500 when opening the link.
When excluding files, does this mean .php files too?

Comment: Try the edited code! If that didn't work tell me your OS and Server name and also change the RewriteBase accordingly

Comment: I tried, it changed to error404. The server is apache 2.4, and i can't tell anything about the OS since its a hosted webserver, but possibly unix

Comment: Try adding this code at the top of you .htaccess file `Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews`

Comment: Sadly still error 404....
{ [02/Apr/2018:17:20:58 +0200] "GET /exampleCategory/573M HTTP/1.1" 404 1114 "-"}

Comment: Copy the whole code that I re-edited and tell me the response tested in ubuntu.

Comment: Still getting 404. In case i do a R=301 it works, but then the php link is visible again...

Comment: RewriteRule ^exampleCategory/([\w\-]+)/?$ index.php?go=$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: To validate an issue with php, i tried to swap "index.php" with "test.html", and it still don't works

Comment: I have found a solution: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755826/mod-rewrite-path-issues
Looks like you have to put "<base href:"" /> in you index.php

Comment: Yeah I always use the / for my assets which is easier